# FreeRTOS xTaskNotifyWait causes some internal mutex assertion to fail

Tags: c, embedded, freertos

#### Context

I'm using the FreeRTOS Task Notifications as a lightweight event-group, as described in the FreeRTOS documentation [here](https://www.freertos.org/RTOS_Task_Notification_As_Event_Group.html). The idea is to make two simple tasks print `Ping` and `Pong` in an alternating sequence, each notifying each other when they have finished printing.

#### Problem

The program compiles successfully, but crashes moments after startup with the following stack trace:

```
assertion "coreID == mux->owner" failed: file "/home/micrified/Documents/Somnox/esp-idf/components/freertos/portmux_impl.inc.h", line 157, function: vPortCPUReleaseMutexIntsDisabledInternal
abort() was called at PC 0x400d58cf on core 1
0x400d58cf: __assert_func at /builds/idf/crosstool-NG/.build/xtensa-esp32-elf/src/newlib/newlib/libc/stdlib/assert.c:62 (discriminator 8)


ELF file SHA256: bd56229aae2c8bfb3479e7a47ebb97d9be7e36483cea95737781c99e1daa0200

Backtrace: 0x400849cd:0x3ffb69a0 0x40084d41:0x3ffb69c0 0x400d58cf:0x3ffb69e0 0x400883ab:0x3ffb6a10 0x40087a3a:0x3ffb6a30 0x40087af9:0x3ffb6a70 0x40082755:0x3ffb6a90 0x40082841:0x3ffb6ac0 0x400d3697:0x3ffb6ae0 0x400d2609:0x3ffb6b00 0x4000bd83:0x3ffb6b20 |<-CORRUPTED
0x400849cd: invoke_abort at /home/micrified/Documents/Somnox/esp-idf/components/esp32/panic.c:155

0x40084d41: abort at /home/micrified/Documents/Somnox/esp-idf/components/esp32/panic.c:172

0x400d58cf: __assert_func at /builds/idf/crosstool-NG/.build/xtensa-esp32-elf/src/newlib/newlib/libc/stdlib/assert.c:62 (discriminator 8)

0x400883ab: vPortCPUReleaseMutexIntsDisabledInternal at /home/micrified/Documents/Somnox/esp-idf/components/freertos/portmux_impl.inc.h:157
 (inlined by) vPortCPUReleaseMutexIntsDisabled at /home/micrified/Documents/Somnox/esp-idf/components/freertos/portmux_impl.h:110
 (inlined by) vTaskExitCritical at /home/micrified/Documents/Somnox/esp-idf/components/freertos/tasks.c:4261

0x40087a3a: xQueueGenericReceive at /home/micrified/Documents/Somnox/esp-idf/components/freertos/queue.c:1542

0x40087af9: xQueueTakeMutexRecursive at /home/micrified/Documents/Somnox/esp-idf/components/freertos/queue.c:635

0x40082755: lock_acquire_generic at /home/micrified/Documents/Somnox/esp-idf/components/newlib/locks.c:157

0x40082841: _lock_acquire_recursive at /home/micrified/Documents/Somnox/esp-idf/components/newlib/locks.c:171

0x400d3697: uart_write at /home/micrified/Documents/Somnox/esp-idf/components/vfs/vfs_uart.c:194

0x400d2609: esp_vfs_write at /home/micrified/Documents/Somnox/esp-idf/components/vfs/vfs.c:420 (discriminator 4)
```

I'm not directly interfacing with any FreeRTOS semaphores or mutex types myself, so I'm unsure what the cause of this error is.

#### Reproducible Example

My program code is fairly simple. I'm running it on an ESP-32 development board and building with the ESP-IDF tool-suite.

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "freertos/FreeRTOS.h"
#include "freertos/task.h"
#include "esp_system.h"
#include "esp_spi_flash.h"


#define A_BIT   0x1
#define B_BIT   0x2

TaskHandle_t handle_task_a;
TaskHandle_t handle_task_b;

void a_task (void *pvParameters) {
    BaseType_t xResult;
    uint32_t value;

    while (1) {

        // Block waiting for notification
        xResult = xTaskNotifyWait(pdFALSE, // Don't clear bits on entry
                                 A_BIT, // Clear own bit on exit
                                 &value, // Save value 
                                 portMAX_DELAY); // Block indefinitely

        if (xResult != pdPASS) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Err: Task A bad notify!\n");
            return;
        }

        // Ignore if bit not set
        if ((value & A_BIT) == 0) {
            continue;
        }

        // Otherwise wait a second
        vTaskDelay(1000 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);

        // Show message
        printf("Task A: Ping!\n");

        // Dispatch notification to task B
        xTaskNotify(handle_task_b, B_BIT, eSetBits);
    }
}

void b_task (void *pvParameters) {
    BaseType_t xResult;
    uint32_t value;

    while (1) {

        // Block waiting for notification
        xResult = xTaskNotifyWait(pdFALSE, // Don't clear bits on entry
                                 B_BIT, // Clear own bit on exit
                                 &value, // Save value 
                                 portMAX_DELAY); // Block indefinitely

        if (xResult != pdPASS) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Err: Task B bad notify!\n");
            return;
        }

        // Ignore if bit not set
        if ((value & B_BIT) == 0) {
            continue;
        }

        // Otherwise wait a second
        vTaskDelay(1000 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);

        // Show message
        printf("Task B: Pong!\n");

        // Dispatch notification to task A
        xTaskNotify(handle_task_a, A_BIT, eSetBits);
    }
}


void app_main(void)
{

    /* Print chip information */
    esp_chip_info_t chip_info;
    esp_chip_info(&chip_info);
    printf("This is ESP32 chip with %d CPU cores, WiFi%s%s, ",
            chip_info.cores,
            (chip_info.features & CHIP_FEATURE_BT) ? "/BT" : "",
            (chip_info.features & CHIP_FEATURE_BLE) ? "/BLE" : "");

    printf("silicon revision %d, ", chip_info.revision);

    printf("%dMB %s flash\n", spi_flash_get_chip_size() / (1024 * 1024),
            (chip_info.features & CHIP_FEATURE_EMB_FLASH) ? "embedded" : "external");

    // Create task A 
    if(xTaskCreate(a_task, "Task A", 512, NULL, tskIDLE_PRIORITY, &handle_task_a) != pdPASS) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error creating task A!\n");
        return;
    }

    // Create task B
    if (xTaskCreate(b_task, "Task B", 512, NULL, tskIDLE_PRIORITY, &handle_task_b) != pdPASS) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error creating task B!\n");
        return;
    }

    // Kick off by notifying task A
    xTaskNotify(handle_task_a, A_BIT, eSetBits);

}
```

Comment: I solved it. There's not enough memory being allocated to the tasks. If I increase it to 8096 words, then it behaves as expected. The reported error is incoherent however.

Answer (score 1):

There are actually 2 errors here, and the error message doesn't tell much about either one.

**Problem 1: Scheduler**

In app_main() you create the tasks but never start the scheduler. If the scheduler isn't running, it never starts the tasks. You need something like

```
    //ERROR: you cant call this before the scheduler starts
    // Kick off by notifying task A
    //xTaskNotify(handle_task_a, A_BIT, eSetBits);

    // Start the real time scheduler.
    vTaskStartScheduler();

    // Will not get here unless there is insufficient RAM.
}
```

https://www.freertos.org/a00132.html

That is only part of the problem, even with that your code will not run. There is another error: you can't call xTaskNotify before you start the scheduler which leads us to the next point...

**Problem 2: Deadlock**

Since we couldn't call xTaskNotify before running the scheduler, nothing will ever happen. The way your tasks are written will create a deadlock.

- Task A waits for notification from B
- Task B waits for notification from A

So the question is where to put the xTaskNotify to prevent deadlock?

There are a few solutions, you can use a button, or a timer interrupt to trigger the first xTaskNotify (if you do this from an ISR make sure to use xTaskNotifyFromISR) and get the whole system running. The easier way is to add it to the startup code of one of your tasks.

```
void b_task (void *pvParameters) {
    BaseType_t xResult;
    uint32_t value;

    //First we wait a little for the scheduler to settle
    vTaskDelay(1000 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);

    // Kick off by notifying task A
    xTaskNotify(handle_task_a, A_BIT, eSetBits);

    while (1) {
```

At this point your code should run as expected.

Comment: I already have a kickoff to avoid the deadlock in my sample code. For some reason without calling the scheduler my example works (see my comment on the post). I'm not sure how